# How to get modification time for a file (in UNIX TIME!) on AIX?

Tags: date, aix

```
$ istat TESTFILE.txt
Inode 2317 on device 12/7       File
Protection: rw-------   
Owner: 4847(testuser)           Group: 346(testuser)
Link count:   1         Length 1480 bytes

Last updated:   Sun Jun 15 08:20:17 2014
Last modified:  Sun Jun 15 08:20:17 2014
Last accessed:  Sun Jun 15 13:03:37 2014

$
```

istat doesn't know any format for UNIX TIME on AIX?

**My question:** How can I display the modification time for a file in UNIX TIME format on AIX?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `perl`:

```
$ perl -le 'print((stat shift)[9])' test.txt
1402577190
```

Or `GNU date`:

```
$ date -r test.txt +%s
```

You can install `GNU date` on `AIX` refer to this [link](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/toolbox/download.html).